# React Native CircleCI pipeline is always failed (Android)

Tags: react-native, cicd, circleci

I am using CircleCI to send APK to QA testers via AppCenter, but when I've upgraded to the RN 0.72 the build is always failing my confi.yml is:

```
    version: 2.1
     jobs: 
  node: 
    working_directory: ~/driver-app
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:lts
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache: 
          key: yarn-v1-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}-{{ arch }}
      - restore_cache: 
          key: node-v1-{{ checksum "package.json" }}-{{ arch }}
      - run: yarn install --ignore-engines
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: node-v1-{{ checksum "package.json" }}-{{ arch }}
      - run:
          name: Decrypt env file 
          command: openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -pass pass:$ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY -d -p -in encrypted-env-staging -out .env
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/driver-app
          paths:
            - node_modules
android-build: 
    working_directory: ~/driver-app/android
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-30-node
    environment:
      APP_VERSION: "2.3.8"
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/driver-app
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/driver-app
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - .gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Decrypt env file 
          command: openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -pass pass:$ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY -d -p -in ~/driver-app/encrypted-env-staging -out ~/driver-app/.env
      - run: 
          name: Decrypt google-services.json
          command:  openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -pass pass:$ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY -d -p -in app/encrypted-google-services -out app/google-services.json
      - run: 
          name: Decrypt production keystore
          command: openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -d -p -in app/encrypted-tkyr-keystore -out app/tkyrkey.keystore -pass pass:$ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY
      - run: 
          name: Change the .gradlew permission
          command: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Assemble Release APK
          command: ./gradlew assembleRelease -PMYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=tkyrkey.keystore -PMYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=$MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS -PMYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=$MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD -PMYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=$MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
      - run:
          name: Rename the APK
          command: mv app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk app/build/outputs/apk/release/test_driver_app_v$APP_VERSION.apk 
      - run:
          name: Install appcenter cli
          command: sudo npm install appcenter-cli -g
      - run:
          name: Distribute APK to testers
          command: appcenter distribute release --debug --app hhmem-tkyr.net/TkyrCaptain --file app/build/outputs/apk/release/test_driver_app_v$APP_VERSION.apk --group "App Testers" --token $APPCENTER_CLI_TOKEN
      - run:
          name: Remove secrets
          command: rm -rf app/google-services.json ~/driver-app/.env.staging app/tkyrkey.keystore
  
workflows:
  build-android-workflow:
    jobs:
      - node:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - test
      - android-build:  
          requires:
            - node
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - test
```

Before I upgrade the RN Library the build is successful, but once I've upgraded to the v0.72 the issue has been appeared.

The failure reason is:

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- Where:
  Script '/home/circleci/driver-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 389
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> React Native needs Node.js >= 16. You're currently on version v14.17.5. Please upgrade Node.js to a supported version and try again.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

Exited with code exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find a solution to this issue, which is to add another command to install the desired NodeJS version V16 using the [`n` node version manager](https://github.com/tj/n).

```
 - steps:
   ...
    - run: sudo n 16
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`circleci/android:api-30-node` seems to have the older node version.
For building android with the latest node version, use the following image

```
 - image: cimg/android:2023.12-node
```

More info @https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/android